# How do I change memory bytes in Visual Studio 2017?

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-2017

I am trying to change bytes in memory, in a memory window, when debugging a C++ project in my Visual Studio 2017.  The memory window is pointing at memory holding code, as I am trying to patch a piece of code quickly (just need to change parameter value) without needing to stop and re-compile.
I also noticed that you cannot change values in the memory window even for data memory.
Is there some hidden configuration setting to let you do that.  It was possible to do this in VS6.

Comment: I am afraid that there is no such option to realize this and you cannot change memory bytes in VS2017.

Comment: Sorry, you are right, forgot to mark it answered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a kind of work-around, that works even for modifying executable code memory.
Here are the steps:

1. Define a spare global pointer in your code (you can actually use any memory pointer in your code as long as you do not care that you will change its value):

   **char* memptr;**
2. Set the pointer in a watch window.
3. Set the pointer value to the memory address that you want to modify.
4. Expend the content (BTW you can use "memptr,100" in your watch window to access more than one byte).
5. Type the updated value in the expended byte value cells.

This works even if you set the pointer to executable machine code memory, so you can use it to patch code.

It can be an **int** pointer or any other type, or you can use a cast in the watch window if you desire to edit any other kinds of objects.

Be careful this can be dangerous, modifying of memory has to be done with the greatest of care.

Comment: You can actually do this even without the variable (at least in VS 2019):
In the watch window, type `((char*)0x7FF6EB623D2D),10` (or whatever the address is).
Then, you can change the 'Value' of each of the bytes, provided you know the correct assembly to use.

Comment: Nice find, works also in VS2013 & VS2015.  In fact you can make the cast not just a char* but pointer to any type including structure/class pointers.

Answer (score 0):

> How do I change memory bytes in Visual Studio 2017?

As far as I know, **Microsoft** does not support changing the memory bytes directly in the latest Visual Studio including **VS2017** and there is no such hidden option to realize it.

**In general**, during debugging, the **Memory** window shows the memory space your app is using. And the **Memory** window isn't limited to displaying data. It displays everything in the memory space, including data, code, and random bits of garbage in unassigned memory.

**Besides**, memory bytes changes with the values of variables in debugger windows such as `Watch`, `Autos`, `Local Variables`, and `QuickWatch` dialogs. Then analyze its changes in memory usage to improve the program. Because of it, we cannot change it directly.

**In addition**, more info about Memory Window, you can check [this official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/memory-windows?view=vs-2019).